# Get Title of Next Media/Song Item to be Played?

Tags: ios, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediaitem

I would like to create a `MediaItem` called `nextItem` which will be the next song to be played, as a preview to the user of what's next.  I don't want to play the next item, just get its title.

The current item is:

```
MPMediaItem *currentItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem];
```

I assumed the next item would be:

```
MPMediaItem *nextItem = [musicPlayer nowPlayingItem + 1];
```

or something, but that doesn't work.  In the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Chapters/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/MPMusicPlayerController/indexOfNowPlayingItem), there is a property indexOfNowPlaying Item:

```
The index of the now playing item in the current playback queue.

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSUInteger indexOfNowPlayingItem
```

So I was just wondering how I would declare a MediaItem `nextItem` as the next track to be played.  I would want to then show its title in a UILabel, but that I can do myself.

I've searched around but I can't find any similar solutions.  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether it has function get nextItem like you said.

This is currently implemented to get next item I do:

```
// MPMusicPlayerController is an iVar variable. 
MPMusicPlaybackState state = MPMusicPlayerController.playbackState;
[MPMusicPlayerController skipToNextItem];
if(MPMusicPlayerController.indexOfNowPlayingItem != NSNotFound)
{
    if(state == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying)
        [MPMusicPlayerController play];
    MPMediaItem *currentItem = MPMusicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem;
    // you get your currentItem and update UI
}
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Does this get the title of the next item?  It seems like it would play the next item